# How to make WooCommerce shop page wider as same as the home page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, page-layout

For some reason, the WooCommerce shop page and product pages are much narrower than the home page. Do you have any idea what setting could cause this behavior? and please help?

btw am using flatsome Theme

Website - https://irokimv.com/

I have tried online css codes nothing happens and also couldn't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how to create a store page template in your theme . In most WooCommerce themes , the store page is designed as a box and not full width.
If you want your product section to be full width, the easiest way is to use css style.
You can fix this by adding the following css style:

```
.category-page-row {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.category-page-row .row {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

[image]

I hope it helped you .